# Gitignore: Ignore all .vscode directories, but include the top-level launch.json

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I want to ignore all `.vscode` directories that may show up in my repository, except for the top-level one. In that top-level one I want to ignore all files except for the `launch.json`.

I tried to no extent:

```
**/.vscode/
!/.vscode/
/.vscode/*
!/.vscode/launch.json
```

```
**/.vscode/
!/.vscode/
!/.vscode/launch.json
```

```
**/.vscode/
!/.vscode/launch.json
```

```
**/.vscode/*
!/.vscode/launch.json
```

```
**/.vscode/
/.vscode/!launch.json
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stumbled on this answer and as some sources today claim that its a good idea to commit the `launch.json` I wanted to provide the correct answer:

```
.vscode
!.vscode/launch.json
```

(You added a slash after !, so the path was considered absolute).

Comment: If you were staring at this wondering why it still doesn't work for you, ensure your `launch.json` has not been previously added to source control. The `.gitignore` only works against untracked files :) If it is tracked, run `git rm -r --cached .vscode/launch.json` and commit its removal.

Comment: Not need for this. Just replace `.vscode` by `./vscode/*` or `./vscode/**` and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend simply ignoring all of these directories:

```
.vscode/
```

and then [manually tracking the file you want](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--f):

```
git add -f .vscode/launch.json
```

The `-f` adds files even if they're ignored, and once the file is tracked the ignore has no effect on it. Git will see changes to `.vscode/launch.json` and you'll be prompted to commit them just like any other file.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put these 2 lines in your `.gitignore`

```
.vscode/*
!.vscode/launch.json
```

First line means, ignore `.vscode` folder with all (using `*` symbol after `/`) of its files.
Second line means, exclude (using `!`) `launch.json` file whereas inside the `.vscode` folder

Comment: This worked for me. Adding the slash and the asterisk did the trick.